# Word2Vec: How values are getting mapped to low dimension

Tags: math, deep-learning, mathematical-optimization, word2vec

I have a vocabulary of size 500000 , i have read that select a dimension size between 100-300 is good, how does such a huge sparse matrix get converted to 100 X 100 dense matrix. I went through a lot of articles but could not understand how the numerical values are getting into the 100 X 100 matrix.

I have read about CBOW and skip gram and theoretically understand how it works, but if I calculate this for each word it would still be a 500000 X 500000 dimension matrix how is it converted to 100 X 100 dimension

Answer (score 1):

You needn't think of anything as being 'converted' from a higher-dimension representation. Every word is given an initial, totally random (but low-magnitude) vector, of the target dimensionality. So, say 100 dimensions.

Then, those 100-dimensional vectors are used (either alone in skip-gram, or in averaged groups in CBOW) to predict nearby words via a shallow neural network – and because the vectors started out random, they're awful at that. But the backpropagation of its prediction errors (as evaluated by either negative-sampling or hierarchical-softmax) nudges the neural-network hidden-layer weights, and then also input-vector weights, to get slightly better at prediction, over and over again.

Eventually, they get as good at prediction as they can with the current training data, within the amount of effort (cycles) you're willing to devote.

At that point, they're still 100-dimensional vectors – they were never anything more – but they will have been moved to relative arrangements that have the other beneficial qualities expected from word2vec.